# MODX REVO, Как поставить фильтр по tv параметрам?

Tags: modx, revo

фильтр как в обычных магазинах, по нескольким метро, по цене итд итп
Ненашел в modx адекватного решения, или нашел, но там нет документации или описания. Сейчас использную if, но он ищет только по одному параметру, только метро и только одну станцию

```
  [[if? 
                        &subject=`[[getCountAvailableTv? &parents=[[*id]] &tvId=`32`]]`
                        &operator=`!=`
                        &operand=`0`
                        &then=`
                        <!-- metro -->

                            <div class="col-md-3">
                            <div class="sidebar_block_head">Округ</div>
                            <div class="scroll-pane">
                                [[!getTvElements?
                                    &parents=[[*id]]
                                    &tvId=`32`

                                ]]    
                            </div>
                      </div>

                        `
                        &else=``
                    ]]
```

Как сделать такую фильтрацию
Выбор 3 метро, цена от 500 до 5000, размер от 5 до 40
?

Comment: Уточни конкретно - используешь ты ресурс+тв или что-то другое, какие тв используешь, как организованы ресурсы, где это надо выводить, каким образом осуществляться должна фильтрация? И тогда шансы на получение адекватного ответа резко возрастут.

Answer (score 1):

1. Сверх адекватное решение для modx: [**mFilter2**](http://docs.modx.pro/components/msearch2/snippets/mfilter2)

   Прекрасно работает с tv, если их добавить в параметр вызова `&includeTВс`.
   Однозначно стоит своих денег.
2. Менее адекватное решение для modx: [**«Фильтрация и управление фильтрами» 1.2 для MODX Revolution**](http://modx-shopkeeper.ru/documentation/modx-revolution/filtracziya-i-upravlenie-filtrami-(tagmanager).html)

   Изначально создан для работы с tv. Бесплатный.